# Add two input decimal numbers starting from integer

Tags: python

I've created a basic script with Input options, but I'm not sure how I can get a simple addition with decimal numbers like 1.2 + 2.3

To this point I'm using

```py
value1 = int(input("Choose one Number"))
value2 = int(input("Choose another Number"))
```

But these are only numbers without decimal points.
Is there any option to use decimal point numbers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) instead of `int`?

Comment: Normally a dot is used to separate the integral and fractional part. If you are coding for users which use a comma, then the fist thing you need to do is to convert the comma to a dot. `float(input("choose one number").replace(",", "."))`

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you follow some good tutorial, this is the kind of things that you will learn by doing that -  and note that SO is really not meant to replace that. You can find a list at https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F . Also, reading the documentation (the official Python doc is very well made) will let you discover lots of useful things...

Answer (score 0):

after receiving the input from the user you could convert it to float instead of int
this should do the trick :

```
value1 = float(input("Choose one Number"))
value2 = float(input("Choose another Number"))
```

for `value1=2.5` and `value2=3.2`
the output was :

```
5.7
```

if you have any questions feel free to ask me in the comments :)
and if my comment helped you please consider marking it as the answer

Comment: Thanks for ur advice, but when i try it the float still stays purple and it gives me an error. Is there any option that i can input my code here like u did? Sorry for the questions, but this is as i mentioned my first time using stackoverflow..

Comment: yes, there is a way, after you paste your code to your post, just mark all of it and press Ctrl+k  :)
and if you could also past the error that you are receiving that  would be grate